# Extended Kalman filter + IMU sensor

Tags: imu, ekf

I'm trying to implement an extended Kalman filter to the accelerometer and gyroscope. However, the result is not good. It seems to have some errors in my codes. I check the equation and code again but I don't find the errors.

'''
import serial
import numpy as np
import math
import time

np.set_printoptions(precision=3, suppress=True)

class ExtendedKalmanFilter(object):
def **init**(self, x0, P0, Q, R):
# initialize vectors and matrices
self.x0 = x0
self.P0 = P0
self.Q = Q
self.R = R
#self.dT = dT
self.currentTimeStep = 0
self.estimates_aposteriori = []
self.estimates_aposteriori.append(x0)
self.estimates_apriori = []
self.estimationErrorCovarianceMatricesAposteriori = []
self.estimationErrorCovarianceMatricesAposteriori.append(P0)
self.estimationErrorCovarianceMatricesApriori = []
self.gainMatrices = []
self.errors = []

```
def stateSpaceContinuous(self, gyro_raw, x_k):
    transition_matrix = np.zeros(shape=(2, 3))
    transition_matrix[0, 0] = 1
    transition_matrix[0, 1] = np.sin(x_k[0, 0]) * np.tan(x_k[1, 0])
    transition_matrix[0, 2] = np.cos(x_k[0, 0]) * np.tan(x_k[1, 0])
    transition_matrix[1, 0] = 0
    transition_matrix[1, 1] = np.cos(x_k[0, 0])
    transition_matrix[1, 2] = -np.sin(x_k[0, 0])

    dxdt = np.matmul(transition_matrix, gyro_raw)
    return dxdt

def discreteTimeDynamics(self, gyro_raw, x_k, dT):
    x_kp1 = x_k + dT * self.stateSpaceContinuous(gyro_raw, x_k)
    return x_kp1

def jacobianStateEquation(self, gyro_raw, x):
    p = gyro_raw[0, 0]
    q = gyro_raw[1, 0]
    r = gyro_raw[2, 0]
    A = np.zeros(shape=(2, 2))
    A[0, 0] = q * np.cos(x[0, 0]) * np.tan(x[1, 0]) - r * np.sin(x[0, 0]) * np.tan(x[1, 0])
    A[0, 1] = (q * np.sin(x[0, 0]) * 1 / np.square(np.cos(x[1, 0]))) + (r * np.cos(x[0, 0]) * 1 / np.square(np.cos(x[1, 0])))
    A[1, 0] = -q * np.sin(x[0, 0]) - r * np.cos(x[0, 0])
    A[1, 1] = 0
    return A

def jacobianOutputEquation(self, x):
    C = np.zeros(shape=(2, 2))
    C[0, 0] = 0
    C[0, 1] = np.cos(x[1, 0])
    C[1, 0] = -np.cos(x[1, 0]) * np.cos(x[0, 0])
    C[1, 1] = np.sin(x[1, 0]) * np.sin(x[0, 0])
    #C[2, 0] = np.cos(x[1, 0]) * np.sin(x[0, 0])
    #C[2, 1] = np.sin(x[1, 0]) * np.cos(x[0, 0])
    return C

def outputEquation(self, x_k):
    return x_k

def propagateDynamics(self, gyro_raw, dt):
    # propagate the a posteriori estimate to compute the a priori estimate
    xk_minus = self.discreteTimeDynamics(gyro_raw, self.estimates_aposteriori[self.currentTimeStep], dt)
    #print("xk minus",xk_minus)
    # linearize the dynamics at the a posteriori estimate
    Akm1 = self.jacobianStateEquation(gyro_raw, self.estimates_aposteriori[self.currentTimeStep])
    #print("Akm1",Akm1.shape)
    # propagate the a posteriori covariance matrix in time to compute the a priori covariance
    Pk_minus = np.matmul(np.matmul(Akm1, self.estimationErrorCovarianceMatricesAposteriori[self.currentTimeStep]),
                         Akm1.T) + self.Q
    #print("Pk minus",Pk_minus.shape)

    # memorize the computed values and increment the time step
    self.estimates_apriori.append(xk_minus)
    self.estimationErrorCovarianceMatricesApriori.append(Pk_minus)
    self.currentTimeStep = self.currentTimeStep + 1

def computeAposterioriEstimate(self, currentMeasurement):
    currentMeasurement_angle = np.zeros(shape=(2, 1))
    currentMeasurement_angle[0,0] = math.atan(currentMeasurement[1,0] / math.sqrt(currentMeasurement[0,0]**2 + currentMeasurement[2,0]**2))
    currentMeasurement_angle[1,0] = -math.atan(currentMeasurement[0,0] / math.sqrt(currentMeasurement[1,0]**2 + currentMeasurement[2,0]**2))
    #print(currentMeasurement_angle.shape)

    # linearize the output equation at the a priori estimate for the time step k
    Ck = self.jacobianOutputEquation(self.estimates_apriori[self.currentTimeStep - 1])
    #print("Ck",Ck.shape)

    Smatrix = self.R + np.matmul(
        np.matmul(Ck, self.estimationErrorCovarianceMatricesApriori[self.currentTimeStep - 1]), Ck.T)
    #print("Smatrix",Smatrix.shape)
    # Kalman gain matrix
    Kk = np.matmul(self.estimationErrorCovarianceMatricesApriori[self.currentTimeStep - 1],
                   np.matmul(Ck.T, np.linalg.inv(Smatrix)))
    #print("Kk",Kk.shape)

    # update the estimate
    # prediction error
    sensor_model = np.zeros(shape=(2, 1))
    sensor_model[0,0] = np.sin(self.estimates_apriori[self.currentTimeStep - 1][1,0])
    sensor_model[1,0] = -np.cos(self.estimates_apriori[self.currentTimeStep - 1][1,0])*np.sin(self.estimates_apriori[self.currentTimeStep - 1][0,0])
    error_k = currentMeasurement_angle - sensor_model
    #error_k = currentMeasurement_angle - self.outputEquation(self.estimates_apriori[self.currentTimeStep - 1])
    #print("error k",error_k.shape)
    # a posteriori estimate
    #print('P danh gia',self.estimates_apriori[self.currentTimeStep - 1].shape)
    xk_plus = self.estimates_apriori[self.currentTimeStep - 1] + np.matmul(Kk, np.array([error_k])).reshape(2,1)
    #print('xk plus',xk_plus.shape)

    # update the covariance matrix
    # a posteriori covariance matrix update
    IminusKkC = np.eye(2,2)
    #print("Iminus",IminusKkC.shape)
    #print(np.matmul(self.R,Kk.T).shape)
    #Pk_plus = np.matmul(IminusKkC,np.matmul(self.estimationErrorCovarianceMatricesApriori[self.currentTimeStep - 1],
                                            #IminusKkC.T)) + np.matmul(Kk, np.matmul(self.R, Kk.T))
    Pk_plus = np.matmul((IminusKkC-np.matmul(Kk,Ck)),self.estimationErrorCovarianceMatricesApriori[self.currentTimeStep - 1])
    #print(Pk_plus.shape)

    # update the lists that store the vectors and matrices
    # Kalman gain matrix
    self.gainMatrices.append(Kk)
    # errors
    self.errors.append(error_k)
    # a posteriori estimates
    self.estimates_aposteriori.append(xk_plus)
    # a posteriori covariance matrix
    self.estimationErrorCovarianceMatricesAposteriori.append(Pk_plus)
```

############################################################

#### Get the raw data

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200, timeout=1)

acc = []
gyro = []
mag = []
old_time = time.time()
###############

x0 = np.array([np.pi/3, np.pi/3]).reshape(2, 1)

x0guess = np.zeros(shape=(2, 1))
x0guess[0] = x0[0] + 4 * np.random.randn()
x0guess[1] = x0[1] + 4 * np.random.randn()

P0 = np.eye(2, 2)
P0[0,0] = 0.1
P0[0,1] = 0
P0[1,0] = 0
P0[1,1] = 0.1

Q = np.eye(2, 2)

R = np.array([[1,0],[0,1]]).reshape(2,2)

KalmanFilterObject = ExtendedKalmanFilter(x0guess, P0, Q, R)
i = 0
while True:
data = ser.readline().decode("utf-8")
dt = time.time() - old_time
old_time = time.time()
data = data[:-2]
data = data.split(',')
if data[0] == "$RAW":
acc = np.array(data[1:4], dtype=float).reshape(3, 1)
gyro = np.array(data[4:7], dtype=float).reshape(3, 1)
mag = data[7:10]
# phi, theta = prediction(initial_state_estimate, gyro, sensor_noise_w_k, dt, 0, 0)
# print(phi, theta)
#################################################################################

```
    KalmanFilterObject.propagateDynamics(gyro, dt)
    KalmanFilterObject.computeAposterioriEstimate(acc)
    print(KalmanFilterObject.estimates_aposteriori[-1]*(180/np.pi))
    #print("tien nghiem",KalmanFilterObject.estimates_apriori[-1])

    # i += 1
    # if i == 1000:
    #     break
#############################################################
```

'''

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* David, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.